# Most Pythonic way to update variables if condition is met

Tags: python

Let's say I have a group of variables that all need to be checked for some condition, and changed if said condition is true. What is the most Pythonic way to go about this? The code below gets to be quite verbose for a large number of variables.

```
def addTen(var):
    if isinstance(var, int):
        var += 10
    return var

var1 = 1
var2 = "2"
var3 = 3

var1 = addTen(var1)
var2 = addTen(var2)
var3 = addTen(var3)

print(var1) #prints 11
print(var2) #prints 2
print(var3) #prints 13
```

Comment: If you have just 3 of them, there is no need to change this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I assume, `addTen` is defined:

```
def addTen(var):
    if isinstance(var, int):
        var += 10
    return var
```

## Update group of variables

There are multiple options, all assume, you get some sort of container for related variables.

### Using list

```
varlst = [1, 2, 3]

if True:
    varlst = map(addTen, varlst)
print varlst
```

or

```
if True:
    varlst = [addTen(itm) for itm in varlst]
print varlst
```

### Using a dictionary

```
vardict = {"var1": 1, "var2": 2, "var3": 3}

if True:
    vardict = {key: addTen(val) for key, val in vardict.items()}

print vardict
```

or

```
if True:
    for key in vardict:
        vardict[key] = addTen(vardict[key])

print vardict
```

## Using class

```
class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

    def addTen(self)
        self.var1 += 10
        self.var2 += 10
        self.var3 += 10

    def __repr__(self):
        templ = "<Container: {self.var1}, {self.var2}, {self.var3}>"
        return templ.format(self=self)

container = Container(1, 2, 3)
container.addTen()
print container
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally you'd pack them into some sort of container (maybe a list?)...

```
var = [1, "2", 3]

for i, v in enumerate(var):
    var[i] = addTen(v)
```

Of course, this case is even easier/cleaner with a list-comprehension since the function is so simple that it can be written as a conditional expression:

```
var = [1, "2", 3]
var = [v + 10 if isinstance(v, int) else v for v in var]
```

or even:

```
var = [addTen(v) for v in var]  # map(addTen, var) works in python2.x, but in python3.x you get an iterator instead of a sequence.
```

Comment: Alternately, `var = map(addTen, var)`.

Comment: @mgilson I see your point with the list, but I really wanted to keep variables to reference them later instead of referencing list indexes. List indexes don't seem as meaningful as variable names which can be descriptive of their value.

Comment: @BigSharpie in that case, you may want a dictionary instead. If they all need to be normal variables, not in a list or dictionary or class, I think you're up a creek sans paddle.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list of names:

```
def addTen(var):
    if isinstance(var, int):
        var += 10
    return var

var1 = 1
var2 = "2"
var3 = 3

for var in [var1, var2, var3]:
    print addten(var)
```

Then you still have the names available later.